# Current in the inductor at $t=0$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, inductance

$L_1 = 5H, L_2=0.2H, M=0.5H, R_0=10 Ω$, and $i_g=e^{-10t}-10 A$. I need to find $i_2$.

[image]

I've started with DE 
$$i_2R_0+L_2(di_2/dt)+M(di_g/dt)=0$$
and solved it for $i_2$, so $$i_2=0.625e^{-10t}+Ce^{-50t}A,$$
where C is constant.

I can't find C because I don't understand how to obtain $i_2(0^+)$. Is it possible to obtain this value? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally seen this question again and found the solution. Maybe someone needs it too. I've started with stating that initially
$$v_2=M(di_1/dt)=-5e^{-10t},$$ so $v_2 (0)=-5 V$. Besides, $$v_2(0)=L_2(di_2(0)/dt)=0.2*(-6.25-50C),$$
so C=0.375. Thus $$i_2=0.625e^{-10t}+0.375e^{-50t}A,$$
and answer in the end of the book gives the same numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The key is opened at ***t=0***. Before that a steady current was flowing in the first network.

So, before t= o, change in current is zero. Thus, $\frac{di}{dt} = 0$.

Thus the induced current in the second network is zero at the instant t=0, i.e, $i_2(0) = 0$

Comment: I'm more interested in i2(0+), not i2(0-), because it's the key for finding C.